# same page anchors within css overflow auto

Tags: html, css, overflow, anchor

how to create anchor to same page but target text is "maintained under" css overflow:auto and therfore is in "scroll sub window". I tried following:

HTML:

```
<a href="#ANCHOR">link</a>

<div class="oneColElsCtr">
<!-- SOME OTHER HTML LINES HERE -->
<p><span name="ANCHOR" class="article"><a href="PDF/1.pdf" target="_new">target</a></p>
<!-- SOME OTHER HTML LINES HERE -->
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.oneColElsCtr  {
    height: 400px;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: auto;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
    margin:auto;
}
```

But after clicking on "link" nothing happens. My goal is to "scroll" whole text in "overflow: auto" to "target"

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` doesn't have a `name` attribute. You need to use `id`.